# C++ std::copy result different from string constructor

Tags: c++

I've encountered some strange behaviour when using std::copy. With

```
std::vector<std::string> chosenIDs{...};
for (const auto& x : chosenIDs) {
  std::string strID("");
  std::copy(std::begin(x), std::find(std::begin(x), std::end(x), '.'), std::begin(strID));
  std::cout << strID << "\n";
}
```

the strID string contains characters it's not supposed to, however

```
std::vector<std::string> chosenIDs{...};
for (const auto& x : chosenIDs) {
  std::string strID(std::begin(x), std::find(std::begin(x), std::end(x), '.'));     
  std::cout << strID << "\n";
}
```

works completely fine. It's clear to me that I should be using the second approach, but it still baffles me as to why the behaviour in the first snippet is different from the second one.

I'm using GCC 5.4.0

Comment: The `copy` writes out of bounds of `strID`  (`copy` does not resize the destination). You could use `std::back_inserter(strID)` as the third argument instead

Comment: @M.M : Write that as an answer, then the OP can accept it, and the rest of us can upvote it.

Comment: someone else can write it up, i have enough rep already

Comment: thank you for clearing that up for me :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When using `std::copy()` it is necessary to make sure that neither range makes out of bounds accesses. The target range starts out empty and there isn't anything done to expand it. Thus, the result is undefined behavior.

The problem can be fixed, e.g., by using a destination iterator growing the target sequence:

```
std::copy(std::begin(x), std::end(x),
            std::back_inserter(strID));
```

Answer (score 3):

As @M.M said:
The copy writes out of bounds of `strID` (`copy` does not resize the destination). You could use `std::back_inserter(strID)` as the third argument instead.
[std::back_inserter](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/back_inserter)